# UPDATE BigQuery query to fix broken timestamps is too complex or resource intensive

Tags: sql-update, google-bigquery

I have several tables that have invalid Standard-SQL `TIMESTAMP` records. These records are nested at least one-level deep in an array. These records break `SELECT *` on these tables, even when using Legacy SQL. They also break exporting the table as JSON. When I try to `UPDATE` these tables to fix the record, it the `UPDATE` errors out unless the statement fixes *all* the broken fields at the same time. This leads to large `UPDATE` statements. Example: https://gist.github.com/dadrian/b83585c23f6cbbcd5f6d6478c92c745d

That `UPDATE` statement is too big to compile!

> Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex

I took a second approach then: `SELECT` out a "fixed-up" `STRUCT` for each parent field containing the arrays with invalid timestamps (e.g. the `p443.https.tls` field) into it's own table. Then `UPDATE` the original table by joining on each "fixed-up struct" table. After each `SELECT` happens, the `UPDATE` looks like:

```
UPDATE `scratch.domain_20170819_copy` target
SET 
  target.p443.https.tls = fixed_https.tls,
  target.p443.https_www.tls = fixed_https_www.tls,
  target.p25.smtp.starttls.tls = fixed_smtp_starttls.tls
FROM `scratch.domain_20170819_copy` AS original
INNER JOIN `scratch.domain_20170819_https_tls` AS fixed_https
ON original.domain = fixed_https.domain
INNER JOIN `scratch.domain_20170819_https_www_tls` AS fixed_https_www
ON original.domain = fixed_https_www.domain
INNER JOIN `scratch.domain_20170819_smtp_starttls_tls` AS fixed_smtp_starttls
ON original.domain = fixed_smtp_starttls.domain
WHERE
  original.domain = target.domain
AND
  original.domain = fixed_https.domain
AND
  original.domain = fixed_https_www.domain
AND
  original.domain = fixed_smtp_starttls.domain
```

This works fine on small enough tables. On larger tables, or tables with more (similarly-broken) fields, the UPDATE statement does not finish, and errors after about 30 minutes with

> Resources exceeded during query execution: ORDER BY operator used too much memory..

How can I fix these tables?

EDIT: The invalid timestamps are due to accidentally outputting an integer timestamp as milliseconds instead of seconds in our datasource. BQ interprets as seconds, which makes the timestamps be in the year 48000.

EDIT: I added the schema and an example data object to the gist.

A quick description of the schema: The relevant data is of the form `a.b.c.tls`, where `tls` is the parent object containing all the broken data. `tls` contains a number of things included `certificate`, which is an object, and `chain`, with is an array of `certificate` objects. A `certificate` contains `parsed.extensions.signed_certificate_timestamps`, which is an array of a struct. On of the fields of `signed_certificate_timestamps` is `timestamp`, which contains the invalid timestamps in question. This effectively means I have a nested invalid timestamp for every `...tls.certificate.parsed.extensions.signed_certificate_timestamps`, and a doubly-nested invalid timestamps for every `...tls.chain.certificate.parsed.....signed_certificate_timestamps`.

Comment: i would suggest you to also show us your actual table's schema and some data example so we will be able to help you

Comment: Added some detail to the gist and the question.

Comment: I'm missing why you need the joins. Can't you transform the timestamps directly in `scratch.domain_20170819_copy` without using the other tables?

Comment: That update statement is too complex to compile. "Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex"

Comment: Another thought: do you get the same error if you `SELECT` into a new table (instead of using UPDATE)? If that works, you could just copy and overwrite this one.